# MySQL calculating the Average and difference for each value?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, average, mean

I'm new to MySQL and I am trying to write a query to determine the average of a column and the difference of each value to that column. 
For Example:

```
Expected Output:
Price   Average   Difference
  2        4          -2
  7        4           3
  3        4          -1
```

That is the result I am hoping for, but I can't quite get the syntax right
Here is my code:

```
SELECT Price, AVG(Price) AS Average,
(AVG(Price) - Price) AS Difference
FROM Item_Price
GROUP BY Price;
```

My results are:

```
Price   Average   Difference
  2        2           0
  7        7           0
  3        3           0
```

Any suggestions? (Here's the Table I am working with)

```
Table: Item_Price

PriceID   Price   Item
   1        2     Ball
   2        7     Socks
   3        3     Book
```

Comment: where is the primary key for this table ? why are you grouping by price ? what is your expected output ?

Comment: if you group it by price then price will always be uqual to average ,and in your example how do you get that average? or is it the count that you want not the average?

Comment: I apologize, I guess it is confusing with the table name up there, (I included it for reference in the query) the table I'll re-edit it

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use an inline view to get the average, and then join the result from the inline view query (one row) to each row in the table.

As an example:

```
SELECT t.Price
     , s.Average
     , t.Price - s.Average AS Difference
  FROM ( SELECT AVG(r.Price) AS Average
           FROM Item_Price r
       ) s
 CROSS
  JOIN Item_Price t
```

This isn't the only approach; there are other query forms that will return an equivalent result.

Comment: @imran: the inline view query returns exactly one row, and we want that row matched with every row from the Item_Price table. So, there aren't any join predicates, that is, there are no conditions to put into an ON clause. In MySQL, including the `CROSS` keyword is entirely optional, it has no effect; it could just as easily be omitted. But my preference is to include it when we omit the ON clause, mostly as a clue to the future reader that the omission of the ON clause was intended, and secondarily, for compatibility with other databases which may require it. Preferable to including `ON 1=1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select price, average, (average - price) as difference
from item_price, (select AVG(Price) AS Average from item_price);
```

Comment: Close, you need price-average and an alias for your subquery.